# LLVM and CLANG - general info

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I actually require CLANG tool. Please let me know whether I can build CLANG from GCC 4.1.2 or I need to have LLVM. If so, would GCC 4.1.2 build both LLVM and CLANG?

Also I need some source-to-source translation (C++ code beautification - inserting new code and comments in between) reference - please provide some reference example if possible?

My observation is that downloading LLVM / CLANG from their offical site via svn / git is very time consuming. It takes around 1 hour to download just 5% of their code. What are the tar file I need to deploy so that I can overcome this one?

Thanks in advance

```
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/llvm-project/!svn/vcc/default'
svn: REPORT of '/svn/llvm-project/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: connection timed out. (http://llvm.org)



install_packages/LLVM 1004> git clone http://llvm.org                                                                             /git/llvm.git
Cloning into llvm...
remote: Counting objects: 655903, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123416/123416), done.
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200MiB | 2 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
warning: http unexpectedly said: '0000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the complete LLVM repository and it took under 10 minutes for me.

Following instructions from their website you can easily build LLVM and CLANG.
There is no issue, in my opinion, in building LLVM and CLANG source code using GCC as I have done it multiple times. LLVM and CLANG use modern C++ and GCC supports it just fine.

GCC is the most used open source compiler in the world and supports more platforms than any other compiler can dream of. So, I am not at all surprised when I see GCC building LLVM or CLANG.

But I use the latest GCC compiler on my system. Try building LLVM and CLANG with GCC 4.1.2(released, February 13, 2007). If it does not work out, which I doubt, try upgrading GCC.

Comment: Did you mean 'Try building LLVM [and] Clang…' or 'Try building LLVM [sans] Clang…' when you said 'Try building LLVM ans [(sic)] Clang…?'